# The type or namespace name 'Storage' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure'

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2013, azure-blob-storage

I updated to Visual Studio 2013 Update 2 RC and to Azure SDK 2.3.

Now I get the following error:

```
The type or namespace name 'Storage' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure'
```

On all three of these:

```
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Auth;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;
```

If I remove these using namespaces then I get the error:

> The type or namespace name 'CloudBlobClient' could not be found (are
>   you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

On this line:

```
CloudBlobClient _blobClient;
```

and I get the little underline in VS suggesting that I add in :

> using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;

Which is the same namespace that that VS is telling me does not exist.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are there any other (non Azure) errors that prevent the solution from compiling?

Comment: I had this issue on our project as well.  It seems that sometimes the upgrade doesn't automatically update the references in your projects.  Double-check all your projects are referencing the new Windows Azure .dlls.

Comment: @mellamokb I updated the azure related dlls through nugget, are there any other dlls that need to be updated?

Comment: I mean actually click on each reference in your project and check the properties.  Make sure they are the new version (2.3), not whatever old version of the SDK you updated from.  I noticed in some of our larger solutions (with 10+ projects), it was hit or miss on which ones the NuGet update actually fixed the references for.

Comment: @mellamokb Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage shows a runtime version of v.4.0.30319 with a version of 3.1.0.1. Is this what im looking for? I believe that is the newest version. Thank you for the help, btw.

Comment: What version of storage client library were you using before upgrading?

Comment: @GauravMantri I believe it was 3.0.

Comment: Would it be possible to upload the project sans any proprietary code?

Comment: @CarstenSchütte I still haven't figured out the problem. Did you also get this problem after upgrading to RC or to the latest SDK?

Comment: @user1308743: Yes.... RC and SDK 2.3

Comment: @CarstenSchütte Problem solved. On Monday WindowsAzure.Storage 4.0 was released on NuGet which fixes this issue. I also installed the RTM of update 2 for VS but I don't believe that is relevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On May 12th Microsoft released WindowsAzure.Storage 4.0 on NuGet. Upgrading to this package from 3.1 fixes the issue.

Comment: Upgrading to v4.0 did not nix the issue here. But changing the target framework for the assembly from v4.0 to v4.5 fixed it.

Comment: After the SDK update , Visual studio will simple show an (!) mark in the nuget packge list if they are not compaitible . So just updating the list will eliminate this issue

Answer (score 1):

add **global::**
using global::Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;

Comment: Note: answers that are very brief and/or are questions back to the poster should probably be comments. You only need 50 rep points to comment under a question - could you move this there?

Answer (score 0):

There has been a buggy Azure SDK 2.3 version that included an invalid Newtonsoft.Json assembly.

Solution (from MSDN forums): "Please try deleting or renaming newtonsoft.json.dll in program files\microsoft sdks\windows azure.net sdk\v2.3\ref and the doing a full rebuild. We will be releasing an update to SDK 2.3 to fix this bug, but the above workaround should hopefully unblock you in the meantime."

See here:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/038a5759-d0a1-448c-8ed3-560e8c8fb0b5/azure-sdk-23-error-compiling-project-with-azurestorage-in-net-4?forum=windowsazuredevelopment

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is obvious but I did not find this solution anywhere else. I eventually figured it out and putting it here for anyone else who faces the same issue.

I cloned by solution to brand new Surface Pro. at the outset, I got like some 30 errors or something. visual studio (2017) usually does this sometimes. After multiple solution clean and rebuild and visual studio restarts, all the errors went away except this one about Storage namespace.

I double checked on my main computer (which has the exact same project and running fine) and found that reference was there but the DLL itself was missing. No missing nuget packages or anything like that.

Eventually, after digging deeper I found that the main computer had the Azure SDK installed but the new Surface Pro obviously did not. I installed the Azure SDK by using the visual studio installer modify/repair option and the problem went away.