# top-level namespace name starts with end of current namespace name

Tags: c#

I have written:

```cs
namespace MyProject.Azure
{
    using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
}
```

I get the error

> [csharp CS0234] [E] The type or namespace name 'Storage' does not exist in the namespace 'MyProject.Azure' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

I guess that because my current namespace ends with `Azure`, I am confusing C# somehow.

How can I use the top-level NuGet package Azure.Storage.Blobs, instead of try to search my current project?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23092712/the-type-or-namespace-name-storage-does-not-exist-in-the-namespace-microsoft

Comment: any reason why you are not using the `using Azure.Storage.Blobs;` before the namesapce declaration?

Comment: You can use `using global::Azure.Storage.Blobs;` or put the using outside and before the namespace declaration instead of inner, that is more conventionnal, unless you have a good reason.

Comment: Thanks it was `global::` after all. I had tried `global.` forgetting it was colons

Comment: @BenzaraTahar it seems to be better for scope and make code less likely to break: https://stackoverflow.com/a/151560/3310334